# Abstract data type?

Tags: social-network-analysis

I don't know, if I can ask this here, but I'm interested to know what kind of *abstract data type (ADT)* does Twitter use to **model relations** between profiles and why. I'm just starting to learn ADTs, so I would like to learn how they work in the real world as well as their applications.

Comment: We are striving to keep quality very high here. Can you please clean up the punctuation and capitalization issues in your post? If you need help, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I also want to mention that I think this is a great question for this site. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

**Any** platform, focused on *social networking* (not necessarily Twitter), at its *core* uses the most appropriate and natural *abstract data type (ADT)* for such domain - a [graph data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29).

If you use Python, you can check nice [NetworkX package](http://networkx.github.io), used for "the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks". Of course, there are many other software tools for various programming languages for building, using and analyzing *network structures*. You might also find useful the relevant book ["Social Network Analysis for Startups: Finding connections on the social web"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020424.do), which provides a nice introduction into the *social network analysis (SNA)* and uses the above-mentioned *NetworkX* software for SNA examples. P.S. I have no affiliation whatsoever with *NetworkX* open source project or the book's authors.